# CalibratedClassifier and RandomSearchCV

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn, calibration

I was wondering what the right steps would be to perform both hyperparameter optimisation and obtain a calibrated model.

I thought the following could be the right way (70% train split, 10% validation split, 20% test split):

```
LOG_model = LogisticRegression(random_state = 2504, n_jobs = -1)

cv_RSKFCV = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10, n_repeats = 5,  random_state = 2504)

search_LOG = RandomizedSearchCV(LOG_model, parameters_LOG, scoring = 'roc_auc', 
                                n_jobs = -1, cv = cv_RSKCV, n_iter = 200,
                                random_state = 2504).fit(X_train, y_train)
best_LOG = search_LOG.best_estimator_
LOG_cccv = CalibratedClassifierCV(best_LOG, cv='prefit', method='isotonic')
LOG_cccv.fit(X_validation, y_validation)
predictions_isotonic = LOG_cccv.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Is this the correct approach or do I need to incorporate the `RandomizedSearchCV` differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks fine:

1. You have completely separated the training and hyperparameter tuning sets from the calibration dataset.
2. You are tuning hyperparameters based on `roc_auc`, which is mostly invariant to calibration.  If you had been tuning based on some other score (one that isn't based solely on rank-ordering, and especially one that depends on a decision threshold*), you might have to worry whether your hyperparameters were optimal for the uncalibrated predictions but suboptimal for the calibrated ones.  (*Anyway, then you'd be encouraged to search this site for proper scoring rules, why accuracy is bad, etc.)

If your data is small, you *might* want to consider using a k-fold cv for the calibration, nesting the hyperparameter search inside that (or vice versa), so that you make more use of all the data.  However, note that in that case the calibration actually produces an ensemble model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation. 

The interesting thing is that hyperparamter tuning on `f1_weighted` provides a way better model (in terms of discrimination) then the `roc_auc`. I was actually thinking about optimising the hyperparameters with `f1_weighted` and then calibrating the classifier afterwards, but I understand that you would advice against this?

Or would it be better to optimise the `brier_score_loss`? However, I read online that I then would first need to calibrate the `RandomForest`, but then without optimal hyperparameters?

Comment: With a cutoff-specific metric like `f1`, I'd probably prefer to set the `CalibratedClassifierCV` as the model in the search.  If you optimize for Brier score, then that will select a model that is better-calibrated over one that is better at distinguishing classes; that might be fine, and maybe then you won't even need to calibrate.  But maybe it's better to again calibrate inside the search.

Comment: So you would then nest the CalibratedClassifierCV in the RandomizedSearchCV like this (excuse the hideous lay out in the comment section):
`LOG_cccv = CalibratedClassifierCV(LOG_model, method='isotonic')`


`search_LOG = RandomizedSearchCV(LOG_ccv, parameters_LOG, scoring = 'f1_weighted',  n_jobs = -1, cv = cv_RSKCV, n_iter = 200, random_state = 2504).fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: Yes.  You could fold the validation set back into the training set in this case.  And, of course, this will take a bit longer to train.

Comment: I will try a few things (F1, ROC_AUC and Brier as scorers with the calibrated classifier cv in the randomizedsearch) and let you know what comes out of it. It will take longer to train because it needs to perform an additional 5 times cv for the calibratedclassifierCV right? Many thanks for your input btw!